# Do images have to be saved in a specific location before inserting them into LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, texworks

I've been trying to insert an image into LaTeX using the [graphicx] package using TeXworks with very little success. The .PNG image I want to insert is currently just saved in my Windows Pictures library, so I was wondering if I have to have the image saved in a specific location before inserting it?

Comment: Be careful with spaces in the path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to put the images into a directory that is searched by LaTeX during the compilation. Usually, the easiest is to put it in the same directory as where the `.tex` file is.

You can as well use the `\graphicspath` command in your preamble to specify the directories searched for graphics. Remember to put each directory in a second pair of braces, like:

```
\graphicspath{{figures/}{/home/me/mygraphics}}
```

(This example is for linux, for Windows, you shall use the correct directory specification. **Remember that this will make your document non-portable.**)

Comment: ...and relative paths to subdirectories, too?

Comment: @Jake the problem is that it's system-specific and the `grfguide.pdf` is void of Windows information :-/

Comment: Thanks @tohecz. I've just tried this and works fine, just had to save the image in documents.

Comment: Relative paths are usually to be preferred, and work the same on Windows as on Linux/Mac. Don't use spaces in any case: TeX really does not like them.

Comment: @JosephWright the guide says something different about Mac. I really don't know and I cannot test it, since I have only linux...

Comment: @tohecz It might do, but that will be about Mac OS 9 and earlier, which used `:` as a path separator. Mac OS X is BSD-based, while on Windows `C:/some/path` is treated by TeX as equal to `C:\some\path` (which of course is not good in TeX terms as it looks like it contains macros).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put the image in the same directory as your .tex file or in case it is in some other directory you can give the full path of the image file in the `includegraphics` command. Example if you put your image files in a directory named `images` within the directory where you have the .tex file then you can use
`includegraphics[options]{./images/xyz.png}`